# Set up Family Safety for child Microsoft Account without creating a Windows 8 profile

Tags: windows-8, parental-controls, windows-phone-8

My son recently got a Windows Phone device, for which we created a Microsoft Account for him. Now in order to play Xbox Live games and other activities he needs to be set up under Family Safety. Searching online it looks like the only way to do so is to create a Windows 8 profile and add him there. He does not use the PC (and I can't add an account getting the "User Profile Service failed" error, but that's a different issue), and only needs this on the phone. Is there a way to link his Microsoft Account to ours without creating a Windows 8 profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by logging in to [windowsphone.com](http://windowsphone.com) and adding his account as a child account of mine.